# AVCaptureSession giving zoomed output

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am trying to make a custom Camera using the AVCaptureSession.
The code and all is working fine. The only Issue is The VideoOutput Layer is zoomed. Which is making my pics zoomed by default.

I tried every thing but couldn't figure out a solution. Here's a small Snippet of the Code am using:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;


AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

**EDIT**
I changed the 
AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect, this corrected the output a little, But the Video Didn't come on the Whole Screen.
PLease see the Screen shot
[image]

Why its showing the White space(The View on which I have set it)? Why its not covering that part too? Is there something am missing?

Comment: Actually `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` is causing your video frame to get fill the height and width with maintaining aspect ratio for the layer. So in the case you might want to try `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect` as video gravity.

Comment: @AdilSoomro I tried That. But that is making the screen awkward.

Comment: @AdilSoomro I made some change in the Answer, COuld you please check,  THanks

Comment: Can you paste the complete code? How are you setting the frame and adding this to view?

Comment: @AdilSoomro Thanks again for the reply. Here's the whole code my .m file http://dpaste.com/3FMJJ4H

Comment: The `imagePreview` seems to be having un-expected frame, can you check the frame of the `imagePreview` while its shown on the view? I guess its not having correct size and origin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69043/discussion-between-jeev-and-adil-soomro).

Comment: @AdilSoomro I too believe the Issue is of imagePreview. I am quite new to the Autolayout and I set my viewController using the Size classes and autolayout. I am also initiallizing the Camera while in did load only. I believe  the video layer is not able to get the correct size. any idea what should I do with it

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue!

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala I faced this issue long ago, and then I some how fixed it and I didn't update the Answer here. Its been more than 2 years. Please write answer, once you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this which I found was that you have to give the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` a frame with **equal width and height**. I got this solution by looking at **Whatsapp Scan Interface**.

And this works perfectly!